# Suggestions for extremely aggressive HTTP caching for REST resources

Tags: rest, scalability, varnish, haproxy

I have a setup where I would like to have extremely aggressive HTTP caching on my internal proxy. Basically, what I want to achieve is a simplistic caching strategy like this:

- any GET request that does not 500x or 400x gets cached indefinitely
- any PUT or POST or DELETE or PATCH that does not 500x or 400x invalidates the resource and it's subpaths (since I only use nested resources and I use them a lot).

I don't plan to have a ridiculous number of subpaths either (around 1000 per root-level resource, and less and less drilling down obviously).

So basically I want to avoid the absolute most of the requests even touching my core app.

I plan to run the caching backend on a separate machine with lots of RAM and evil storage, and there is going to be one such machine (so I don't have to expire across a cluster or anything like that).

Which proxy cache would be better for this task? Varnish or HAProxy? What are the settings that I should look for to achieve this kind of expiry? Is this a common pattern to make REST servers caching-friendly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAproxy is only a load balancer. It will not do any caching for you.

Varnish is a good choice for your described case. As for the configuration, you are best off to send the caching details (ttl/expiry time and cachability) from your backend that will instruct varnish on cache handling of the document.

Comment: Yep, I have to look into Varnish and VCL. Thanks!